# Ionic3 - Testing. Test if a Page is pushed on the NavigationStack

Tags: testing, ionic3

Im really new to Testing. I set up TedBed. Now i try to test my first Component "MyApp" which looks like this:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp implements OnInit {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(
    private app:App, 
   ) {

  }

  pageTwo() {
    let navs = this.app.getActiveNavs();
    let nav = navs[0]
    nav.push(AnotherPage);
  }


  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Template:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" persistent="true">
    <ion-header>
        <ion-navbar>
            <ion-title>
                MyApp
            </ion-title>
        </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button menuClose (click)="pageTwo()" ion-item>
                <ion-label>
                    AnotherPage
                </ion-label>
            </button>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

As you can see i, i have a mehtod that navigate to "AnotherPage" if the menu-button is clicked. This is working - Now i try to test this behavior:

```
describe('MyApp Component', () => {
  let fixture;
  let component;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyApp],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: NavController, useFactory: () => NavControllerMock.instance()},
        {provide: App, useFactory: () => AppMock.instance()},
      ]
    })
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyApp);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component instanceof MyApp).toBe(true);
  });

  it('should navigate to Antoherpage if pageTwo() is called', () => {
    component.pageTwo()
    // ...
  });


});
```

I have no clue what i have to do, to test if the "AnotherPage" is pushed to the Navstack after method "pageTwo" is called.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some research i got it working. It was easier than i thought:

```
  it('should navigate to Antoherpage if pageTwo() is called', () => {
    component.pageTwo()
    expect(nav.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith(AnotherPage);
  });
```

since i use the ionic-mocks package (https://github.com/stonelasley/ionic-mocks). I dont have to spy on the nav.push manually.